# how to remove ui-state-hover by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have to remove ui-state-hover class for mouseover and click on button.I am using p:commandButton of jsf.

For that,
I use jquery sample code:

```
   $("#button").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("btn01");
    }, function() {
        alert("mouseover working");
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
    });

    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("btn01");
    }, function() {
        alert("click not working");
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
    });
```

Using above jQuery,Mouse hover on button is working properly.
But mouse click on button, style button changed to ui-state-hover. How to remove ui-state-hover?

Comment: What do you want exactly? When you remove `ui-state-hover` on `mouseover` , There is not any class `ui-state-hover` when you click?? Because it has been removed already.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('#button-hover').attr('class'), '<<--- button-hover say current class.'); //onload
console.log($('#button-click').attr('class'), '<<---- button-click say current class.');

$("#button-hover").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).addClass("btn01");
   $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
  console.log($(this).attr('class'), '<<--- button-hover say current class.');
})

$("#button-click").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("btn01");
  $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
  console.log($(this).attr('class'), '<<---- button-click say current class.');
});
```

```css
.btn01 {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
}

.ui-state-hover {
   background: #ff0000;
   color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-hover" style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="ui-state-hover"> button hover </button>

<button id="button-click" style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="ui-state-hover"> button click </button>
```